# What is this kind of jQuery statement called?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I just started an internship with a company and I am learning jQuery on the fly. Yesterday my boss sat down with me and showed me some new statements including 'if' and '%'.. Here's an example of the code he created yesterday. He then told me that I need to comprehend and learn how to do what he had done. So I figured a good way to do this would be to start from the beginning of it, however when searching Lynda.com tuts I don't really know what to look for. He's out of town so I cannot disturb him. Could somebody please help direct me how to learn about these functions? I believe he referred to them as conditions, is this correct?
What we were attempting to do was create a solid 1 px collapsing border around some divs for an ecommerce template.

Thanks!

```
function resetCategoryBorders(){
 $(".topLevelCategoryContainer").each(function (index) {
        var catwrapwidth=$("#wp_categorywrapper").width();
        var toplevelwidth=$(".topLevelCategoryContainer:eq(0)").width();
        var availablewidth=(toplevelwidth>0 ? parseInt(catwrapwidth/toplevelwidth) : 0);
        if (parseInt(index+1) % 4 !=0 && index!=$(".topLevelCategoryContainer").length)
        {
            $(this).css("border-right","0px");
        }
        $(this).appendTo($("#wp_categorywrapper"));


      });
```

Comment: Do a jQuery tutorial. Have a look at the jQuery documentation pages for "each", "css" and "appendTo".

Comment: To read about jQuery methods: `http://api.jQuery.com/<methodName>`. As for 'conditions,' they're simply JavaScript, not jQuery.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp, % is Modulus.

Comment: Please, no w3schools links... https://devdocs.io/javascript/operators/arithmetic_operators

Comment: @AnilKumar rather than link the misleading w3schools page, please use [the MDN documentation on operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4zt01x0t/3/ - An commented explanation of the code.

Comment: @Jhawins and MDN links are even better.

Comment: You will have a far easier time understanding all this is you learn how to do it properly. Begin with JavaScript basics, then move onto jQuery (as jQuery is a JS library, you will understand things better with proper foundational knowledge).

Answer (score 0):

These are actually fairly simple JavaScript features.

`if` is a conditional block, you provide with a boolean (or something that evaluates to a boolean) and everything in the block will be skipped if that boolean is `false`.

As for `%`, it returns the remainder of a division operation.
17 / 4 is 4 with a remainder of 1. So `17 % 4 === 1`

As for learning more about JavaScript, I suggest you read [**Eloquent JavaScript**](http://eloquentjavascript.net/) (Yes, all of it). After you have a proper understanding of the language, learning jQuery should be a breeze.

Comment: Only thing thats missing is about the ternary operator(?). I assume the OP would not know what that is also. Nice straight answer